# How can I theoretically determine the effect of acoustic perturbations on laminar-turbulent transition in a heat plume (i.e. rising smoke)?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, acoustics, navier-stokes

I've done some preliminary reading on how Tollmien-Schlichting waves play a part in these perturbations, but is there a formula that connects sound frequency with the transition stage?

Comment: The boundary between two different density gases can be inherently unstable and small perturbations may be all that's necessary to initiate the growth of the modes radiated by the instability.  Does that help?